# C# MVC Textbox MultiLanguage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I have a view with a TextBox for input. However it seems like it doesn't support all Spanish characters. The upside down question mark doesn't seem to work. Is there a simple way to get around this?

```
  <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.Name, new { style = "width:400px", maxlength = 150 })%>
```

Comment: What HTML is it generating for you? The `TextBoxFor` helper generates a pretty simple `<input type="text" />` tag so it should just work.

Comment: Yeah its an input type text. I'll try to trace it again. It might be a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Inside your web.config you are using utf-8:

  ```
  <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
  ```
- Inside the `<head>` section of your site you have a `<meta>` tag:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  ```
- Your view files are utf-8 encoded with BOM on the disk